# Is there a better way to write this recursive function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have written a small recursive function which is meant to test whether a is a power of b. The full exercise from *Think Python* is:

*A number, a, is a power of b if it is divisible by b and a/b is a power of b. Write a function called is_power that takes parameters a and b and returns True if a is a power of b. Note: you will have to think about the base case.*

```
def is_power(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return True
    elif a % b == 0:
        a = a/b
        return is_power(a, b)
    else:
        return False
```

Is there a more condense way in which I can write this function? Also, is it appropriate to have the function return itself in this manner? The recursive functions I've been seeing so far don't seem to return themselves, rather they just call themselves and return something else. Thanks

Comment: The function isn't "returning itself" - it is returning "the result of evaluating itself" - which is, of course, precisely what recursion means! (On different arguments, of course, otherwise the recursion would never end.)

Comment: The base case could be more basic: if `a == b`, you can still divide `a` by `b` to get `1`, leading to a recursive call of `is_power(1, b)`. (Anything other than 0 to the zeroth power is 1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just a bit more concise:

```
def is_power(a, b):
    if a % b != 0:
        return False
    return a == b or is_power(a/b, b)
```

As for "a recursive function that returns itself" as it is in this example, this is a good structure and it's called "tail recursion".

The reason that it's good is because some compilers know how to do tail-recursion optimization which makes you code run faster and consume less memory than a "normal" recursion.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it in one line:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    return a == b or (a%b == 0 and is_power(a/b,b))
```

In general, returning `True` or `False` is response to comparisons is more verbose than just returning the comparisons themselves. Comparisons are already Boolean-valued.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, there is a more efficient (and more verbose) algorithm you can use.

Note that for a constant `b`, `is_pow(a,b)` takes `O(N^2)` time where `N` is the bit size of `a`.

You can go faster by observing that if `a` is a power of `b`, then bit-sizes of `a` and `b` give information about the power of `b` that divides `a` and is close to `sqrt(a)` in size. This way, each recursive call reduces the bitsize of `a` roughly by half.

```
def is_power(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return True
    elif a % b != 0:
        return False
    n = a.bit_length()
    m = b.bit_length()
    x = pow(b, n//m)
    return is_power(a//x, b)


def is_power_quadratic(a, b):
    if a % b != 0:
        return False
    return a == b or is_power_quadratic(a//b, b)

# In [26]: %timeit is_power_quadratic(2**(10**3), 2)                             
# 597 µs ± 3.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# In [27]: %timeit is_power(2**(10**3), 2)                                 
# 10 µs ± 26.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score -4):

I usually don't do assignments, but because know one seemed to know what it was I gave it. But here's what's happening, parameters for functions are pretty much variables between the parenthesis, so when you type the function you would put the value of the variables in parenthesis, so "is_power(2, 4)" would set 2 to the variable a, and set 4 to the variable b. Now Return simply sends the outcome back to the session. Make sure that True and False are capitalized, otherwise it will think they are variables. But if you ran this program like this, "is_power(2, 4)", after execution it would print True on the screen since the power of 2 is 4.

```
def is_power(a, b):
    power = pow(a)
    if power == b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: A few issues here: first, the question asks whether `a` is a power of `b`, your description seems to indicate the opposite. Also, the [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#pow) function in python requires at least two arguments; you've only shown 1. Third, this is an exercise in recursion, but your answer doesn't use recursion. Feel free to try to correct it!